# Stop pagination from occurring if user taps and drags on a seek bar outside the slider handle

Tags: ios, html5-video, mobile-safari, wkwebview, uipageviewcontroller

We have a UIPageViewController housing multiple web views that contain HTML5 video players.

When the user tries to tap and drag on the seek bar (aka HTML input rage sliders), without using the slider handle, the UIPageViewController thinks that the user wants to paginate to the next view.

[image]

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

I've created a sample project with plain range sliders inside webviews to demonstrate this issue. Link to project: https://github.com/karlingen/HTMLInputRangeWithPageVC